# Execute JQuery function when JQuery library has loaded

Tags: jquery

I need to initiate this function when the JQuery library has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flexslider").flexslider({
.....
```

The problem is I'm implementing the page on a platform where the jquery library is loaded in in the footer, so after my code. How can I wait until this has loaded before I execute my code? Thanks!

edit: I can't move the library bytheway nor put my code after the library in the footer

Comment: put this code after the line of jquery including

Comment: Use AMD like require.js (http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: I can't move the library bytheway

Comment: @user1937021 most voted comment suggests you not to move your library but the posted code script only.

Comment: Can't move my code after the library either

Comment: Then you can't make it work! flexislider needs jQuery functions so either you have to move your jquery up or put your script below it. Otherwise forget it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your best option is simply to move your `script` tag to *after* the `script` tag that includes jQuery.

   ```
   <script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="your-code.js"></script>
   ```
2. If for some reason you really, really, really can't do that, you can use a timer loop:

   ```
   (function() {
       doStuff();
       function doStuff() {
           if (typeof jQuery !== "function") {
               setTimeout(doStuff, 50);
               return;
           }
           // ...your code here...
       }
   })();
   ```

   But again, #1 is really the best choice.